# Discrepancy in Bitwise Shift Calculation Results

Tags: go, types, bit-shift

I'm encountering a discrepancy in the output of my Go program, specifically with the variables x1 and x2. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
package main

var n uint = 10
const N uint = 10

func main() {
    var x1 byte = (1 << n) / 100
    var x2 byte = (1 << N) / 100
    println(x1, x2)
}
```

Expected output:
10 10

Actual Output:
0 10

Curious about the reasoning behind the difference, seeking explanation.

Comment: Constant expressions get evaluated with unspecified precision, so it's properly calculating 1024 / 100, whereas in the first expression the 1 just gets shifted outside of the byte immediately. (Is my understanding at least)

Comment: From [the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Operators): "If the left operand of a non-constant shift expression is an untyped constant, it is first implicitly converted to the type it would assume if the shift expression were replaced by its left operand alone." `1` is the untyped constant here, and `n` being `var` makes the expression non-constant, so that `1` has to have type `byte` thus shifting by 10 will make it 0.

Comment: @isaactfa, I agree, the shift operation with constant N does not overflow.
Bahamas, if you remove the "/ 100" from both lines, only the second line errors out: "cannot use (1 << N) (untyped int constant 1024) as byte value in variable declaration (overflows)"

Comment: @isaactfa I will accept your answer once you provide it.

Comment: @ChristophBerger Go will truncate the value and store the least significant 8 bits. I wouldn't categorize it as an overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant expressions get evaluated with unspecified precision. Everything in the assignment to `x2` is constant so it's properly calculating 2<sup>10</sup> / 100 = 1024 / 100 = 10. Whereas in the first expression the 1 is treated as a `byte`, meaning it just gets shifted out immediately. That the 1 must get treated as a `byte` is in [the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Operators):

> If the left operand of a non-constant shift expression is an untyped constant, it is first implicitly converted to the type it would assume if the shift expression were replaced by its left operand alone.

1 is the untyped constant on the left here, and `n` being `var` makes the expression non-constant, so that 1 has to have the type of its assignee `x1`, i.e. `byte`.